# Why does one of my django model classes not return any data, when using a filter

Tags: mysql, django, view, model

Here is the first section of the view:

```
class PropertyView(models.Model):
    idproperty = models.IntegerField(db_column='idProperty', primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address1 = models.CharField(db_column='Address1', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address2 = models.CharField(db_column='Address2', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

I am trying to filter on the first field, 'idproperty'.  Here is the Django view:

```
def property_detail(request, pk):
    
    prop = Propertytable.objects.get(pk=pk)
    propertylist = PropertyView.objects.filter(idproperty=prop.idproperty)
    
    context = {
        "property": propertylist,
        "thisprop": prop
       
    }
    return render(request, "property/property_detail.html", context)
```

The 'prop' is returned correctly (from a mysql table).  But the 'propertylist' returns nothing. I do not get any error.
The database view, when run directly in mysql, returns the correct data.  I constructed the model manually, and I wonder if I have made a mistake.  In the same app, there are other views (i.e. model based on mysql views) which work fine.

Comment: Could you share the PropetyView model ?

Comment: Hi, I could do that, but I think I have now solved the problem.  It seems that if you specify a filter on a field that is specified to the django model as a primary key, it does not work. My mysql view does not have a primary key, but the django model does. so I can simply use get() instead of filter(), and the data is retrieved ok.